# Does Flow or TypeScript have a way to use the return type of a function as a separate type

Tags: c++11, typescript, flowlang

C++ has the [`decltype`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype) keyword that allows getting the return type of a function without evaluating it, and I was wondering if the typed dialects of JS had something similar. I would imagine it working something like this:

```js
let foo = () => 'bar'
let baz: typeof foo() // uses the inferred return type of foo()
```

Comment: for typescript this does not seem to be possible.

Comment: Apparently it's a [proposed feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606)